# Trying to get image to change on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to show a playlist on my website as a png image.
I have 2 playlists that must be shown.
The playlist will change on an image press.

I have 4 button images, 'CD1up', 'CD1down', 'CD2up' and 'CD2down'.

I would like to have these buttons changing what current playlist is being shown, but also showing the buttons correct state. For example, is playlist1 is being shown, then 'CD1up' must be shown, and 'CD2down' shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some notes:

- If you give each image an `id` attribute, you can use `document.getElementById` to get a reference to that element once the page is loaded.
- Then you can set the `src` property on that element to a new URL to change the image.
- Make sure your `script` tag is *after* the elements in the HTML (just before the closing `</body>` works) so that the elements exist when you want them.
- You can add a `click` event handler to any element on the page. Most browsers support `addEventListener` but some older versions of IE still require you to use `attachEvent` to hook up the handler. So you see people with functions that look something like this:

  ```
  function hookEvent(element, eventName, handler) {
      if (element.addEventListener) {
          element.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
      }
      else if (element.attachEvent) {
          element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, handler);
      }
      else {
          element["on" + eventName] = function(event) {
              return handler.call(this, event || window.event);
          };
      }
  }
  ```

So for example, if you have this `img`:

```
<img id="myImage" src="/path/to/img.png">
```

This cycles through four images on click:

```
<!-- This must be AFTER the `img` above in the HTML,
     just before your closing /body tag is good -->
<script>
(function() {
    var myImage = document.getElementById("myImage"),
        images = [
            "/path/to/img1.png",
            "/path/to/img2.png",
            "/path/to/img3.png",
            "/path/to/img4.png"
        ],
        index = -1;

    hookEvent(myImage, "click", imageClick);

    function imageClick() {
        ++index;
        if (index >= images.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
        myImage.src = images[index];
    }
})();
</script>
```

You can get a *lot* of utility functionality and smooth over browser differences using a decent library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries), although if **all** you want to do on the page is change the images sometimes and handle a click or two, that might be overkill.

Comment: @JadeMulholland: Good deal, glad that helped!

Comment: I'm still a little confused though since the array contains 4 images, yet I have a total of 6 to work with, being both states of cd1 buttons, both states of cd2 button and both the playlists.

Comment: @JadeMulholland: I just picked that example at random (having four images and cycling through them on click) to show how you can respond to clicks and update the image being shown.

Comment: ahh right! So should I add a link to the imageClick function? For example

<a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:imageClick();" >
<img id="myImage" src="/path/to/img1.png" alt="CD 1 Active" />
</a>

Comment: @JadeMulholland: No need for `javascript:` links, just hook the `click` event of the anchor. If you're going to do that, though, you have to prevent the default action of the click from within the event handler, which you can't readily do with the `hookEvent` above. I'd suggest using a library to help smooth things over.